# Shellscript not running in crontab to execute sqlcmd

Tags: linux, cron, redhat, sqlcmd

I am using `crontab` in Red Hat to run a shell script that will output a CSV file to the directory. I can execute the script manually but when I run it via `cron`, it doesn't run. My script is:

IndividualInformation.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.0 -d TestDB -U xx -P xxxx -Q "EXEC BPE.IndividualInformation_GetList" -o "IndividualInformation.csv" -h-1 -s"," -W
exit 0
```

my crontab looks like this:

```
12 30 * * * /home/admin/cronTab_SQL/IndividualInformation.sh 2> /tmp/crontab_script_log.txt 2>&1
```

i can't seem to run the script in crontab and when i checked the logs (crontab_script_log.txt), the logs was empty.

Comment: ... to confirm, running `/home/admin/cronTab_SQL/IndividualInformation.sh 2> /tmp/crontab_script_log.txt 2>&1` works fine?

Comment: the log.txt file was created but has no input data recorded. while the csv was not created.

Comment: ... sorry I meant to ask if it works fine when you run it manually from the shell?

Comment: yes, manually, the csv file was created in the directory. the only problem is that when i run it in cron, it doesn't create the csv

Comment: OP did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
12 30 * * *
```

is not a valid time specification. The order is `minute`, `hour`, `day of month`, `month`, `day of week`. There's no hour 30.

If you want to run the script every day at 12:30, it should be:

```
30 12 * * *
```

Also, in the command

```
2> /tmp/crontab_script_log.txt
```

should be

```
> /tmp/crontab_script_log.txt
```

You're redirecting `stderr` later with `2>&1`, you need to redirect `stdout` to the file.

Comment: sir it doesn't work, the csv file was not created and the log file was updated but with no records

Comment: Have you checked your system log to see if the script is running.

Comment: You could start by adding `* * * * * touch /tmp/cron-is-running` to your crontab and checking if `/tmp/cron-is-running` is created on the next minute interval.

Comment: i just execute command chmod 755 in the shell script and run it. since it works manually, i didn't execute other commands other than putting it in crontab. i am still new to linux and still learning step by step, may i know where can i find the system log you referring to?

Comment: ... also as suggested earlier, check whether the `.csv` file has been been created in your home directory in case you did not add the `cd ...` to your crontab.

Comment: i just assume that the cron is running since when i use lt -ltra, the time of the txt file was updated in /tmp folder

Comment: Hi Sir, there is no .csv file in my home directory

Answer (score 2):

I did have this problem.
So it runs correct in command line, not in crontab.
But looking at log you will probably find this :
*sqlcmd: command not found*

run

> which sqlcmd

and change your script to precise sqlcmd :

> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 1.2.3.4 -U sa -P xxxxxx -Q "BACKUP
> DATABASE [${nombase}] TO DISK = N'${fexp}' WITH RETAINDAYS = 7,
> NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'${basename} - Sauvegarde', SKIP, NOREWIND,
> NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10" 2>&1 1>> $txt

fexp is the destination file, txt in a personnal log file

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your file is somewhere else (possibly in your home directory).

Try this crontab:

```
12 30 * * * cd /home/admin/cronTab_SQL && /home/admin/cronTab_SQL/IndividualInformation.sh 2> /tmp/crontab_script_log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Since he has the absolute path to the script, why would he need to `cd`?

Comment: It is required because it looks like the script uses a relative path (really just filename) for the output file.  If the script used an absolute name with `-o` then it would not be required.

Comment: The output file is `/tmp/crontab_script_log.txt` that's an absolute path.

Comment: I think OP indicated that `/tmp/crontab_script_log.txt` is created, but `IndividualInformation.csv` is missing.  The `cd` will help get this file created in a known directory.

Comment: @Bar I think your answer gets at the root cause.  I'm going to upvote it.

Comment: just to take note that the csv file was located at /home/admin/cronTab_SQL/Individual.csv if i run it manually

Comment: You'll want to refer to @Barmar's solution.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the csv file was created but it was saved in the /root folder.

i just edit my script to save the csv file to the directory i want :

`sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.0 -d TestDB -U xx -P xxxx -Q "EXEC BPE.IndividualInformation_GetList" -o "\home\admin\crontab_SQL\IndividualInformation.csv" -h-1 -s"," -W`